# PHP Creating Association Arrays inside a For Loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, associations, push

```
<?php
    $facet_fields = array (
    "dx-tx295" => array (
    "T",1348,),
    "dx-z1" => array (
    "F",1,
    "G",2,
    "E",3,
    "D",4,
    "C",5,
    "H",6,
    "B",7,
    "I",8,
    "J",9,
    "K",10,
    "A",11,
    "L",12,
    "M",13,)
    )
    $catalogue = array();
    $value = array();
    for ($x=1;$x<count($facet_fields);$x++)
    {
         for($y=0;$y<count($facet_fields[$x]);$y+2)
         {
            $current = $facet_fields[$x];
            $spot = ($current[$y] => $current[$y+1]);
            array_push($value, $spot);
         }
    }
    for($i=0;$i<count($facet_fields);$i++)
    {
        $spot2 = ($facet_fields[$i]=>$value);
        array_push($catalogue, $spot2);
    }   
    print $catalogue
    print $value    
?>
```

I am trying to assign each number in the first array to its associated letter, and then add the association to a spot in a new array value. Then I am trying to associate the value arrays to the facet_field arrays and add them to catalogue. It is having a problem with the assigned associations such as the line with $spot.

Is it possible to do this? Or can I not include this many variables in an association? How would I make an associated array in an array like this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php  You have a problem with your array declarations.

Comment: It would be best to add, in addition to the code provided, and example of the desired output.

Comment: @SomeKittens: though I do see that OP's array declarations are probably not as good as they could be (assuming associative arrays would suit the need better than numerically indexed arrays) I do not see any issue with the way they are being declared.  Enlighten me please.

Comment: While they're syntactically correct, what it looks like Tom is trying to do is create an associative array (it possibly could be numerical).  Currently his array contains both string and integer objects.

Comment: @sberry
The desired output would give:
    dx-tx295
      T
       1348
    dx-z1
      F
       1
      G
       2
      E
       3
    ...and so on

So that each value array is associated filed under its position in the catalogue, and each letter value in the array has an associated number value that follows it. Thanks guys.

Comment: @TomWall:  Edit your question with formatted version of your desired output.

Comment: @sberry The output is irrelevant.I am more interested in creating the catalogue array that consists of the "dx" terms, each of which is attached to at least one value array that has a letter and the following number.

Comment: @TomWall: That is not irrelevant.  It is critical.  You show what you want the `$catalogue` array to look like, because thus far, it is unclear.

Comment: If have read the question several times. Sorry, but i do not get it. Could you please add the $catalogue = array ( ... with your wanted structure ... ); ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Is it possible to do this?

   Yes, it is possible to transform the array.
2. Or can I not include this many variables in an association?

   No, that is not a problem. The $facet_files array is small and processable.
   Memory problems arise only, when arrays are really, really large.
3. How would I make an associated array in an array like this?

   By iterating over the `$facet_fields` array, getting its keys and values and inserting 
   them into a new array with the desired structure. I think you make this a bit  complicated, by using for-loops and indexing the $values array with the iterator variable. When you insert new values into an array they are automatically indexed numerically.
   In other words: stop doing `$facet_fields[$x]`.

   You might provide the `$catalog = array( key => value );` because it's not really clear which structure the target array must have.